# Run cucumber scenario outline parellely

Tags: cucumber, gherkin, cucumber-java

I have more than 50 different types of input which I am defining under Example keyword in feature file and it is consuming more time for executing.Is there any way to run these input parellely?.I don't want any test runner for this approach.
Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Consider some alternative approaches to how you are doing this bit of testing

1. Write a unit test instead. Cucumber is really bad at exhaustive testing (its just not designed for it). With a unit test you can write something that is faster, and deals dynamically with the different input types, without those types needing to be written in the test.
2. Pull the input types up and out of cucumber and use them to drive multiple calls of cucumber (so you are paralleling Cucumber calls rather than trying to parallel scenario calls).
3. Write a scenario for each type of input e.g. get rid of the outline. This will make it much easier for existing tools to run things in parallel.